# How to get the icon of an app by it's AppID given by Get-StartApps on Windows 10 and above

Tags: windows, powershell, startmenu

I get the StartApps from Windows via `Get-StartApps` (powershell) which gives me the `Name` and the `AppID`.

I need to get the icon of of the app via it's id to be able to display it (or at least the absolute path to the executable). But most AppID contains not the full path to the exectuable I'm not able to extract the icon. `Get-StartApps` don't seems to provide more infos out of the bo.

Starting the app by adding `shell:AppsFolder\${appid}` works normally.

What is the official way to get the meta information like icon by the AppID?